# How to write the external interrupt callback function of Linux kernel v3.10?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I use the Linux kernel v3.10. I have a question about the following code. After the `action->handler()` function is executed, why should the interruption be determined whether the interruption has been opened, and if it is not opened, it should be closed?

This function comes from Linux kernel v3.10.

```c
irqreturn_t
handle_irq_event_percpu(struct irq_desc *desc, struct irqaction *action)
{
    struct pt_regs *regs = get_irq_regs();
    u64 ip = regs ? instruction_pointer(regs) : 0;
    irqreturn_t retval = IRQ_NONE;
    unsigned int flags = 0, irq = desc->irq_data.irq;

    do {
        irqreturn_t res;

        trace_irq_handler_entry(irq, action);
        res = action->handler(irq, action->dev_id);
        trace_irq_handler_exit(irq, action, res);
                /* here is my question */
        if (WARN_ONCE(!irqs_disabled(),"irq %u handler %pF enabled interrupts\n",
                  irq, action->handler))
            local_irq_disable();

        switch (res) {
        case IRQ_WAKE_THREAD:
            /*
             * Catch drivers which return WAKE_THREAD but
             * did not set up a thread function
             */
            if (unlikely(!action->thread_fn)) {
                warn_no_thread(irq, action);
                break;
            }

            irq_wake_thread(desc, action);

            /* Fall through to add to randomness */
        case IRQ_HANDLED:
            flags |= action->flags;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        retval |= res;
        action = action->next;
    } while (action);

#ifndef CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL
    add_interrupt_randomness(irq, flags, ip);
#else
    desc->random_ip = ip;
#endif

    if (!noirqdebug)
        note_interrupt(irq, desc, retval);
    return retval;
}
```

If this is the case, do I still need to add and turn off the interrupt operation in my interrupt callback function? However, the 3rd edition of `LDD` recommends not to prohibit interrupts as much as possible.

Comment: Before you start with a software you should get how hardware looks like. The interrupts can be disabled on both sides of the Interrupt Controller (from the device side and from the CPU side). Here is about CPU side. IRQ handler is run with CPU interrupts disabled. The device side of interrupt is what driver must enable (otherwise device most likely won't issue a new interrupt) and IRQ handler must take care of not disabling.

Comment: @0andriy I am still a little confused. In the code above, I marked the place where **here is my question**. I understand that if the interruption is not closed, it will be printed if it is not closed, and then executes the local_irq_disable () function to close it to close Interrupt.

Comment: Which side of the interrupt you are talking about? The code you cited is about **CPU** side of the interrupt.

Comment: @0andriy I understand your first comments, whether it is on the side of the device, or the CPU side, it cannot be prohibited when using IRQ, but the code I quoted, I understand that if the CPU side interruption is not closed, the warning is printed. At the same time, the `local_irq_disable` function is executed. I think it is a bit contradictory.

Comment: Yes, correct. If CPU side of IRQ is enabled by any reason it will warn and force disable it again.

Comment: @0andriy [my driver code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218993/irq-interrupt-obtaining-abnormal-possibilities)，So I have to use the `local_irq_disable` function when applying for IRQ?

Comment: I **highly** recommend you to start reading books. SO is not a debugging / personal trainer forum. Do your homework.