# IRQ interrupt obtaining abnormal possibilities

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt, gpio

I am using the processor of `Allwinner A40i`. The kernel version is `3.10`, an external `STM32`, `STM32` generates a IO interrupt per `8ms`, and the `A40i` obtains the interrupt signal (rising edge) through the GPIO. There is no other component in the middle. I found that occasion occasionally there will I got multiple interruptions in `8ms`, but when I used the oscilloscope to grab the waveforms, the waveforms were normal.

a apart of `device tree`:

```auto
spiio{
    compatible = "dobot, spiio";
    spiio_gpio = <&pio PI 10 6 default default default>; /*PI 10, 0->input/6->EINT, 1->level, 2->down pull, 1->data*/
    clocks = <&clk_pio>;
};
```

spiio.c:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/of_gpio.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/sys_config.h>
#include <linux/major.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/poll.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/pinctrl/pinconf-sunxi.h>


static int MajorDevNum = 0;
static int SpiioNum = 0;
static int IrqNum = 0;
static struct class *SpiioClass;
static int IrqOccurred = 0;
static  wait_queue_head_t WaitQueue;
static spinlock_t RWLock;

static void SetIrqOccurred(int newIrqOccurred)
{
        spin_lock_irq(&RWLock);
        IrqOccurred = newIrqOccurred;
        spin_unlock_irq(&RWLock);
}

static irqreturn_t spiio_irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
//      pr_debug("spiio irq ocurred on IRQ %d\n", irq);
        if (irq == IrqNum) {
                SetIrqOccurred(1);
                wake_up_interruptible(&WaitQueue);
        }
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int spiio_drv_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
//      pr_info("start read\n");
#if 1
        int ret = 0;
//      pr_info("this is read. IrqOccurred = %d\n", IrqOccurred);
//      ret = wait_event_interruptible(WaitQueue, IrqOccurred);
        ret = wait_event_interruptible_timeout(WaitQueue, IrqOccurred, msecs_to_jiffies(10));
        pr_info("wait end-timeout, ret = %d, IrqOccurred = %d\n", ret, IrqOccurred);
        if (IrqOccurred) SetIrqOccurred(0);
        if (ret > 0) {
                return 1;
        } else if (ret == 0){
                return 0; //timeout
        } else {
                pr_err("wait_event_intrruptible_timeout return %d\n", ret);
                return -1;
        }

#endif
}

/* write(fd, &val, 1); */
static int spiio_drv_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *offset)
{
   return -1;
}

static int spiio_drv_open(struct inode *node, struct file *file)
{
    int err = 0;
    pr_info("this is open\n");
#if 0
    spin_lock_init(&RWLock);
    init_waitqueue_head(&WaitQueue);
    IrqNum = gpio_to_irq(SpiioNum);
    if (IS_ERR(IrqNum)) {
        pr_err("irqNum is err\n");
        free_irq(IrqNum, NULL);
        return -1;
    }
    //if ((err = request_irq(IrqNum, spiio_irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "spiio_irq", &pdev->dev)) < 0)
    if ((err = request_irq(IrqNum, spiio_irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "spiio_irq", NULL)) < 0)
    {
        pr_err("requst_irq failed, err = %d\n", err);
        free_irq(IrqNum, NULL);
        return -1;
    }
    pr_info("add irq %d on pin %d success.\n", IrqNum, SpiioNum);
#endif
    return 0;
}

static int spiio_drv_close(struct inode *node, struct file *file)
{
#if 0
    free_irq(IrqNum, NULL);
#endif
    return 0;
}

static long spiio_drv_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
        return 0;
}

//static unsigned int spiio_drv_poll(struct file *file, struct poll_table_struct *wait)
static unsigned int spiio_drv_poll(struct file *file, struct poll_table *wait)
{
#if 0
//    pr_info("this is poll.\n");
    int ret = 0;
    poll_wait(file, &WaitQueue, wait);
    if (IrqOccurred)
    {
        mutex_lock(&RWLock);
        IrqOccurred = 0;  //need lock
        mutex_unlock(&RWLock);
//      pr_debug(" an irq occurred. return %d\n", POLLIN);
        return POLLIN;
    } else {
//      pr_debug("no irq occurred, IrqOccurred = %d\n", IrqOccurred);
        return 0;
    }
#endif
#if 0
    if (irq_set_affinity_hint(irqNum, cpumask_of(1)) < 0) {
        pr_info("failed to set affinity\n");
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}


static struct file_operations spiio_drv = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = spiio_drv_open,
    .read = spiio_drv_read,
    .write = spiio_drv_write,
    .release = spiio_drv_close,
    .unlocked_ioctl = spiio_drv_ioctl,
    .poll = spiio_drv_poll,
};

int spiio_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    int err = 0;
    struct gpio_config pinConfig;
    char pinName[32] = {0};
    unsigned int config = 0;
    struct device_node *nd = pdev->dev.of_node;
    if (!nd) {
        pr_err("no found device tree node\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if ((of_gpio_named_count(nd, "spiio_gpio") <= 0))
    {
        pr_err("no found spiio_gpio node\n");
        return -1;
    }
    SpiioNum = of_get_named_gpio_flags(nd, "spiio_gpio", 0, (enum of_gpio_flags *)&pinConfig);
    if (!gpio_is_valid(SpiioNum))
    {
        pr_err("gpio isn't valid\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (gpio_request(SpiioNum, pdev->name) < 0)
    {
        pr_err("gpio request failed, GPIO:%d\n", SpiioNum);
        gpio_free(SpiioNum);
        return -1;
    }
    sunxi_gpio_to_name(pinConfig.gpio, pinName);
    pr_info("pinName = %s\n", pinName);
    pr_info("index = %d\n", pinConfig.gpio);
    pr_info("mul_sel = %d\n", pinConfig.mul_sel);
    pr_info("pull = %d\n", pinConfig.pull);
    pr_info("drv_level = %d\n", pinConfig.drv_level);
    pr_info("data = %d\n", pinConfig.data);
    config = SUNXI_PINCFG_PACK(SUNXI_PINCFG_TYPE_FUNC, pinConfig.mul_sel);
    pin_config_set(SUNXI_PINCTRL, pinName, config);
    if (pinConfig.pull != GPIO_PULL_DEFAULT) {
        config = SUNXI_PINCFG_PACK(SUNXI_PINCFG_TYPE_PUD, pinConfig.pull);
        pin_config_set(SUNXI_PINCTRL, pinName, config);
        pr_info("set pull:%d\n", pinConfig.pull);
    }
    if (pinConfig.drv_level != GPIO_DRVLVL_DEFAULT) {
        config = SUNXI_PINCFG_PACK(SUNXI_PINCFG_TYPE_DRV, pinConfig.drv_level);
        pin_config_set(SUNXI_PINCTRL, pinName, config);
        pr_info("set drv_level:%d\n", pinConfig.drv_level);
    }
    if (pinConfig.data != GPIO_DATA_DEFAULT) {
        config = SUNXI_PINCFG_PACK(SUNXI_PINCFG_TYPE_DAT, pinConfig.data);
        pin_config_set(SUNXI_PINCTRL, pinName, config);
        pr_info("set data:%d\n", pinConfig.data);
    }
    if (gpio_direction_input(SpiioNum) < 0)
    {
        pr_err("gpio_direction_input failed %d\n", SpiioNum);
        gpio_free(SpiioNum);
        return -1;
    }
    MajorDevNum = register_chrdev(0, "spiio", &spiio_drv); /* /dev/spiio */
    if (MajorDevNum < 0)
    {
        pr_err("failed to get major device number\n");
        gpio_free(SpiioNum);
        return -1;
    }

    SpiioClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "spiio_class");
    if (IS_ERR(SpiioClass))
    {
        pr_err("spiio class has an error\n");
        unregister_chrdev(MajorDevNum, "spiio");
        gpio_free(SpiioNum);
        return PTR_ERR(SpiioClass);
    }
    device_create(SpiioClass, NULL, MKDEV(MajorDevNum, 0), NULL, "spiio%d", 0); /* /dev/100ask_spiio0 */
    pr_info("gpio is ok, spiio num is %d\n", SpiioNum);
#if 1
    spin_lock_init(&RWLock);
    init_waitqueue_head(&WaitQueue);
    IrqNum = gpio_to_irq(SpiioNum);
    if (IS_ERR(IrqNum)) {
        pr_err("irqNum is err\n");
        free_irq(IrqNum, NULL);
        gpio_free(SpiioNum);
        unregister_chrdev(MajorDevNum, "spiio");
        return -1;
    }
    //if ((err = request_irq(IrqNum, spiio_irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "spiio_irq", &pdev->dev)) < 0)
    if ((err = request_irq(IrqNum, spiio_irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "spiio_irq", NULL)) < 0)
    {
        pr_err("requst_irq failed, err = %d\n", err);
        free_irq(IrqNum, NULL);
        gpio_free(SpiioNum);
        unregister_chrdev(MajorDevNum, "spiio");
        return -1;
    }
    pr_info("add irq %d on pin %d success.\n", IrqNum, SpiioNum);
#endif
#if 0
    if (irq_set_affinity_hint(irqNum, cpumask_of(1)) < 0) {
        pr_info("failed to set affinity\n");
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}

int spiio_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
#if 1
    free_irq(IrqNum, NULL);
#endif
    device_destroy(SpiioClass, MKDEV(MajorDevNum, 0));
    class_destroy(SpiioClass);
    unregister_chrdev(MajorDevNum, "spiio");
    gpio_free(SpiioNum);
    pr_info("gpio remove ...\n");
    return 0;
}

struct of_device_id ids[] = {
    {.compatible = "dobot, spiio"},
    {},
};

static struct platform_driver chip_demo_gpio_driver = {
    .probe = spiio_probe,
    .remove = spiio_remove,
   /* .shutdown = spiio_remove,*/
    .driver = {
        .name = "spiio",
        .of_match_table = ids,
    },
};

static int __init spiio_init(void)
{
    int err;
    err = platform_driver_register(&chip_demo_gpio_driver);
    return err;
}

static void __exit spiio_exit(void)
{
    platform_driver_unregister(&chip_demo_gpio_driver);
}
module_init(spiio_init);
module_exit(spiio_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

a part of `dmesg`:

```auto
[ 6568.744425] this is open
[ 6568.745230] wait end-timeout, ret = 10, IrqOccurred = 1
[ 6568.746052] wait end-timeout, ret = 9, IrqOccurred = 1
```

This is just one of the abnormal kernel printing. Through the kernel printing, two interruptions have been obtained in GPIO Controller. What is the reason for this?

Comment: You run your real handler asynchronously while being in hard IRQ context. Switch to threaded context (`request_threaded_irq()`) with `IRQF_ONESHOT ` set.

Comment: @0andriy  I changed `if ((err = request_irq(IrqNum, spiio_irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, "spiio_irq", NULL)) < 0)` to `if ((err = request_threaded_irq(IrqNum, NULL, spiio_irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_ONESHOT, "spiio_irq", NULL)) < 0)`  , the result are same.

Comment: The messages are printed in the read handler. How do you know when the interrupt occurred?

Comment: @IanAbbott Because I put the `IrqOccurred` variable to `0` in the Read Handler. If it is not interrupted again, the interrupt function is called again, why does `IrqOccurred` become `1` again?

Comment: The read handler may have been called some milliseconds after the `IrqOccurred` was set to 1, and may have called again just before `IrqOccurred` was set to 1 again by the next interrupt.

Comment: @IanAbbott I used `spin_lock_irq`.

Comment: You used `spin_lock_irq`. So what?